# getting words from the list of characters

Tags: r, list

I have a list of characters (hashtags), where some of elements includes more than one word.

It looks like this:

```
head(hashtags)
[[1]]
[1] "FutureofAccountechs"

[[2]]
[1] "internet" "Cornwall"

[[3]]
[1] "beer"

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] "popsicle" "natural" 

[[6]]
[1] "coffee"  "ethical"
```

I need to extract individual words from this list. Accessing them accessing via element number:

```
> hashtags[[5]]
[1] "popsicle" "natural" 
> hashtags[5][[1]]
[1] "popsicle" "natural"
```

Any ideas how I can "flatten" them, so they are

```
"FutureofAccountechs"
   "internet" 
   "Cornwall"
   "beer"
   NA
   "popsicle" 
   "natural" 
   "coffee"  
   "ethical"
```

Comment: [`unlist`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/unlist.html)?

Comment: Is the indentation meaningful??????????